# plotly subplot with ggplot and grouped legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I'm trying to arrange all the plots i.e. barplots that have a common legend in the `plotly` subplot. I have created individual subplot using `ggplotly` and `hide_legend()` doesn't seem to solve my problem. With plotly it is easier to do the same thing but I have to forget about ggplot. Can anyone help me in this matter?

Here is the code describing my problem:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
data <- dget("loan_pred.data")
factor_col_names <- names(data)[map_lgl(data,is.factor)]
n<- 1
create_barplot_plotly <- function(feature){
  g <- ggplot(data) +
        aes_string(x=feature)+
        ggtitle(paste(feature))+
        geom_bar(aes(fill=Loan_Status),position = "fill")+
        ylim(0,1+0.10)+
        ylab("proportion") + theme_bw()

  g <- ggplotly(g)

  if (n %% length(factor_col_names)!=1){
      g <- hide_legend(g) 
  }

  n <<- n +1
  return(g)

}  
plotly::subplot(map(factor_col_names,create_barplot_plotly),
                  nrows = 3,margin = 0.06,titleX = TRUE,titleY = TRUE)%>%
                  layout(title="BoxPlots")
```

I have uploaded the data using dput on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ceqXDTRT99IQWZibmwe7h8mgnHZqNaYY) and edited the code to reduce dependencies.

Comment: Can you provide `data` using `dput()`?

Comment: i'm using loan prediction data set from [Analytics Vidhya](https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-loan-prediction-iii/#).

Comment: A link may stop to work in the future. It is better to add it to your post with `dput()`.

Comment: Please provide 'data'

Comment: I have uploaded the data using dput on google drive and update the code so it can work without problems and sorry for the late response.